# Django Rest Framework read-write flat serializer using to_internal_value() and to_representation()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've successfully implemented writable-nested-serializer following the drf documentation and I've also been able to change its representation using to_representation() method to look cleaner.

\initial data structure where POST works fine with modified crete()

```
{
    "id": 1033,
    "client": {
        "client_name": "BAC"
    },
    "brand": {
        "brand_name": "SDA"
    },
    "order_date": "2018-01-25",
    "shipment_date": "2018-01-26"
}
```

\data structure after applying to_representation() and PATCH works with modified update() fine but not POST and PUT does not.

```
    {
        "id": 1033,
        "order_date": "2018-01-25",
        "shipment_date": "2018-01-26",
        "client_name": "BAC",
        "brand_name": "SDA"
    }
```

However, I can't seem to implement properly the to_internal_value() method so that I can have a writable-nested-serializer using the new representation. Below is the error I get despite customizing the create() method and POSTING with the required data.

\POST data

```
{
    "order_date": "2017-10-26",
    "shipment_date": "2017-11-11",
    "client_name": "ABC",
    "brand_name": "DEF"
}
```

\Error message

```
{
    "client": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "brand": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Below is my code. The update() method works properly when using PATCH. But POST and PUT doesn't work so I'm thinking I'm missing some code linking the create() and to_internal_value() methods properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

/serializers.py

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer()
    brand = BrandSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'client', 'brand', 'order_date',
                  'shipment_date',)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        representation = super().to_representation(obj)
        client_representation = representation.pop('client')
        brand_representation = representation.pop('brand')
        for key in client_representation:
            representation[key] = client_representation[key]
        for key in brand_representation:
            representation[key] = brand_representation[key]
        return representation

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        client_internal = {}
        brand_internal = {}
        for key in ClientSerializer.Meta.fields:
            if key in data:
                client_internal[key] = data.pop(key)
        for key in BrandSerializer.Meta.fields:
            if key in data:
                brand_internal[key] = data.pop(key)
        internal = super(OrderSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        internal['client'] = client_internal
        internal['brand'] = brand_internal

        return internal

    def create(self, validated_data):
        client_data = validated_data.pop('client')
        brand_data = validated_data.pop('brand')
        client, created = Client.objects.get_or_create(
            client_name=client_data['client_name'])
        brand, created = Brand.objects.get_or_create(
            brand_name=brand_data['brand_name'])
        order = Order.objects.create(
            client=client, brand=brand, **validated_data)
        return order

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        client_data = validated_data.pop('client')
        brand_data = validated_data.pop('brand')
        client, created = Client.objects.get_or_create(
            client_name=client_data['client_name'])
        brand, created = Brand.objects.get_or_create(
            brand_name=brand_data['brand_name'])
        instance.brand = brand
        instance.client = client
        instance.order_date = validated_data['order_date']
        instance.shipment_date = validated_data['shipment_date']
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: The response suggests that you don't send client and brand in your post request to create order. This is response from the serializer validation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. My question was incomplete. I did send a POST/PATCH with the required data which resulted in the mentioned error. Edited my question already.

Comment: in your request, it is client_name and brand_name. In your order serializer, there are not such fields - there are only client and order ( as nested serializers ).

Comment: I get what you mean. If I only want a writable-nested-serializer then I don't have any problems with the HTTP methods. My problem lies after customizing the representation using to_representation() and then adding write functionality back again using to_internal_value().  If you could enlighten me on these it would be great. I've been searching proper documentation and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Any reason why you need to re-implement these 2 methods? They seem to be doing the very same or similar thing that the original ones. And you could handle the client_name,brand_name little bit easier. Anyway your client and brand are required fields by default, so that's why it reports they are required. So try to make them optional by adding  ``required=False`` for the client and brand nested serializers.

Comment: Well the reason is that I want the api to look cleaner. My model is actually more complicated with other nestings still so I want a way to flatten it but retain the logic. I've tried your suggestion of required=False but no luck. I think the clue is in the docs of to_internal_value() method "The return value will also be passed to the .create() or .update() methods if .save() is called on the serializer class." I'm thinking this is why PATCH works bec my update() method has instance.save(). Just not sure how to implement .save() on the create() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and as i suggested in my comment, this should help you:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = ClientSerializer(required=False)
    brand = BrandSerializer(required=False)
```

With this, i am able to send POST request with your json input and order is created.

Comment: It works! I guess I was wrong and initially thought you wanted me to put 'required=False' in my models.py fields. Should've known it was on my serializer as it was the relevant thing here. Thank you so much for your time and patience with me.

Comment: @柳Lau no problem. happy to help. I learned something myself;-)